# Can Grunt tasks navigate "up" from the folder they are run in?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying to structure my assets so that multiple projects can share a "phase" of the build script. For example, if I have 3 web-based products that all use Bootstrap and jQuery, I want to only source the libraries from a shared "library".

The folders are proposed to be structured like this:

```
shared
  -sharedGrunt.js (file)
  -lib (folder)
    -bootstrap (folder)
    -jQuery.js (file)
app1
  -Gruntfile.js (file)
  -src (folder)
    -images (folder)
    -js (folder)
    -etc
app2
  -Gruntfile.js (file)
  -src (folder)
    -images (folder)
    -js (folder)
    -etc
```

I want Gruntfile.js in each "app" folder to be able to "import" or otherwise execute `sharedGrunt.js`. I haven't crossed that bridge yet because I'm stuck at the very first proof of concept test: a simple copy.

So, in one of the app's `Gruntfile.js` files, I have a copy task that looks like this:

```
copy: {
  externalTest: {
    expand: true,
    src: '../shared/lib/jQuery.js',
    dest: 'dev/js/jQuery.js',
    flatten: true
  }
}
```

As you can see, I try to go UP one level from the Gruntfile. Which is the directory containing "shared", "app1", and "app2". And then navigate back down into the shared lib folder in order to grab jQuery.

The task is "successful" (no actual error is thrown), but no files are copied.

How can I accomplish my goal? Will I need to put a "catch-all" gruntFile into a "parent" folder that contains all of the projects? I don't want developers to require checking out the whole parent. I want developers to be able to check out "app1" and "shared" and run with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by observations in Xavier's answer, I forged ahead and determined that I had two flaws:

1. I should simply provide the destination directory. If I try to provide a filename, it will make an additional directory with the name of what I thought would be the filename; this is per Xavier's observation.
2. If you don't issue a "cwd" for the copy, it reproduces the entire directory tree from the source side.

So, the following:

```
share: {
  expand: true,
  src: '../common/lib/jquery.js',
  dest: 'dev/js/'
}
```

results in a file found in the destination as '"dev/common/lib/jquery.js"'. This is not intended behaviour.

---

SOLUTION:

1. Supply the destination as a directory, not a filename. It will use the original filename.
2. Issue a CWD before the copy so that the source path is not merged into the destination path.

Working task:

```
share: {
  expand: true,
  cwd: '../common/lib',
  src: 'jquery.js',
  dest: 'dev/js/'
}
```

Results in a file sourced at `"../common/lib/jquery.js"` and ending up at destination `"dev/js/jquery.js"` as intended.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird - Grunt has no problem with going up any level, and on my machine your code indeed copies 1 file.

**However,** your use of `expand` cause grunt to use the `dest` property as a directory, so your file ends up being `dev/js/jQuery.js/jQuery.js` (note the repetition).

Fixed by doing:

```
copy: {
  externalTest: {
    expand: true,
    src: '../shared/lib/*.js',
    dest: 'dev/js',
    flatten: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it should work; you also pointed me towards supplying only the destination directory instead of filename. There were a few other problems, but ultimately I ended up with my solution thanks to this answer.